# Subtract days from a date in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to subtract "number of days" from a date in Bash. I am trying something like this ..

```
echo $dataset_date #output is 2013-08-07

echo $date_diff #output is 2   

p_dataset_date=`$dataset_date --date="-$date_diff days" +%Y-%m-%d` # Getting Error
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You are specifying the date incorrectly.  Instead, say:

```
date --date="${dataset_date} -${date_diff} day" +%Y-%m-%d
```

If you need to store it in a variable, use `$(...)`:

```
p_dataset_date=$(date --date="${dataset_date} -${date_diff} day" +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Comment: I had to modify this to `$ date "--date=${dataset_date} -${date_diff} 1 day" +%Y%m%d` to actually subtract the date... otherwise it would have added one day. Is there anything i missed?

Comment: @x_mtd Yes, you need to set the variable `date_diff`.  Set it to the number of days that you want to subtract.

Comment: Very slight improvement to the command - date --date="${dataset_date} -${date_diff} day" +%Y-%m-%d. Just to make it clearer that the --date is an option to the date command, and the double-quotes are being used to correctly represent the STRING passed to the --date option.

Comment: How to find the difference if dataset_date is in this format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

Answer (score 37):

one liner for mac os x:

```
yesterday=$(date -d "$date -1 days" +"%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're not on linux, maybe mac or somewhere else, this wont work.
you could check with this:

```
yesterday=$(date  -v-1d    +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

to get more details, you could also see

```
man date
```

Comment: getting "date: invalid option -- 'v'"

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: it is bash scripting

Answer (score 6):

To me, it makes more sense if I put the options outside (easier to group), in case I will want more of them.

```
date -d "$dataset_date - $date_diff days" +%Y-%m-%d
```

Where:

```
 1. -d --------------------------------- options, in this case 
                                         followed need to be date 
                                         in string format (look up on $ man date)
 2. "$dataset_date - $date_diff days" -- date arithmetic, more 
                                         have a look at article by [PETER LEUNG][1]
 3. +%Y-%m-%d -------------------------- your desired format, year-month-day
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution:

```
echo $[$[$(date +%s)-$(date -d "2015-03-03 00:00:00" +%s)]/60/60/24]
```

It calculates number of days between *now* and *2015-03-03 00:00:00*

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution:

```
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
yesterday="$(date -d "$today - 1 days" +%Y%m%d)"
echo $today
echo $yesterday
```

Comment: This is in essence answer from @Jeremy

Answer (score 2):

Below code gives you date one day lesser

```
ONE=1
dataset_date=`date`
TODAY=`date -d "$dataset_date - $ONE days" +%d-%b-%G`
echo $TODAY
```